# Server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting. APC

Tags: performance, apache, apc

I have a Drupal installation running inside a server with this configuration:

```
StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers    15
MaxClients        50
MaxRequestsPerChild  1000
```

I have installed APC and MemCached. APC is working as the way shown in this image:

[image]

But I'm getting this error in Apache logs:

```
[Fri Feb 15 14:04:48 2013] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

Concurrent users at the moment of the error were less than 50 and ps -aux | grep apache shows that all apache process are in S status.

What could be happening? Could be APC is running out of memory? I have spent last 3 hours searching about the problem but any solution works for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, Apache HTTPd reports that, at a given time which may have lasted less that a second, there have been more than MaxClients concurrent connections.
I don't know how you count concurrent "users", but a single browser can open a lot more than one connection to the same server (for example, to retrieve images or CSS in parrallel).